# setCellType(CellType.STRING) is deprecated, Use explicit setCellFormula(String), setCellValue(...) or setBlank() to get the desired result

Tags: java, apache-poi

poi version:4.1.2

```java
@Deprecated
@Removal(version = "5.0")
void setCellType(CellType cellType)
```

as noted in Cell class docs,it says `setCellType()` is deprecated, and suggests using `setCellFormula()` to realize the same function, but it doesn't give one example on how to realize it.

The question is:
How to use `setCellFormula()` to realize the same function as
`setCellType(CellType.STRING)`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you want your cell to contain?

Answer (score 3):

The cell type depends on the cell content. That's why set cell type independent of cell content is deprecated.

So

> Use explicit `setCellFormula(String)`, `setCellValue(...)` or
> `setBlank()` to get the desired result.

means the following:

`Cell.setCellFormula` will always result in a cell having cell type `FORMULA`. Or it leads to cell type `ERROR` when the formula results in an error.

`Cell.setCellValue` will result in a cell having cell type `STRING` when value is `String`, `NUMERIC` when value is numeric or date, or `BOOLEAN` when value is `boolean`.

`Cell.setBlank` will always result in a cell having cell type `BLANK`.

So no need to explicit set cell type.

Also read the following part of [Cell.setCellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType-):

> ... If what you want to do is get a String value for your numeric
> cell, stop! This is not the way to do it. Instead, for fetching the
> string value of a numeric or boolean or date cell, use `DataFormatter`
> instead. ...

So don't use `Cell.setCellType` to `STRING` to get the value as a `String`. Instead do using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to do so:

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
...
java.lang.String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not use `setCellFormula()` to imitate `setCellType(CellType.STRING)`, but you can use `setCellValue(String someString)` to set a cell's type to `CellType.STRING` and set the cell value at the same time.

In other words, with `setCellFormula()`, `setCellValue()`, and `setBlank()` you don't just set the cell content, but at the same type you inherently set the cell type. If you use any of these methods, and call `getCellType()` afterwards, you will get the correct cell type. There shouldn't be a use case, where you set a cell type, but not any cell content.